# How would you create a call to a function inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript

Please take a look at the code below. The problem is that when I press a checkbox it will always be the last value in noGroupKeys that will be sent to the function and not 0-j since the for loop has already ended when I press a checkbox. Is it even possible to create the bellow code so that it calls the method noGroupKeys for every j whitout having to send the enitre noGroupKeys list as a parameter and then loop through the list in "GenerateGraph.checkWhatGraphDataToPrint" method?

```
for (var j = 0; j < noGroupKeys.length; j++) {
    //Enable Checkboxes
    var currentNoGroupKey = noGroupKeys[j];
    $("#officialCheckBox").click(function() {
        GenerateGraph.checkWhatGraphDataToPrint("No_Group", currentNoGroupKey);
    });
    $("#validCheckBox").click(function() {
        GenerateGraph.checkWhatGraphDataToPrint("No_Group", currentNoGroupKey);
    });
}
```

Thanks